# Export Playwright testInfo.project.name outside of test.spec.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, playwright-test

Hi I am trying to get the testInfo.Project.Name value that is generated during a test execution (in test.spec.ts) and export to be used in another module (for instance customReport.js). I have tried a few things but none have worked.

What I have tried in customReport.js:

1. `var _globals = require("../node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/globals")` result: the lib folder does not exist in that path.
2. `var _globals = require("../node_modules/playwright/lib/common/globals.js")` result: console log returns undefined.
3. Declared

```
var projectDetail = {browser: ''} export {projectDetail} in customReport.js

import { projectDetail } from './customReport.js' in test.spec.ts
test('sample', async ({page}, testInfo) => {packageDetail.browse = testInfo.project.name});
```

result : console log returns undefined in customReport.js